# Convert a stream into a list

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to convert a stream into a list. To do so I have tried this code :

```
try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(args[0]))) {
    List<String> lines =  stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But then the compiler tell me that :

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `List<Object>` to `List<String>`

Also I've tried this way :

```
try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(args[0]))) {
    List<String> lines =  Stream.of(stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But then I have this error :

> This static method of interface Stream can only be accessed as Stream.of

which happen every time, whenever I use the Stream.of methods.

Can someone help me out, please?

Comment: Perhaps it's a compiler bug. Your first snippet works on my Eclipse.

Comment: @Eran what is the JRE version you use ? I have the 1.8.0_91.

Comment: "This static method of interface Stream can only be accessed as Stream.of" did you mind case? If you write `stream.of` then you are trying to access the static method from an instance. And Stream.of(stream) doesn't make much sense to me ...

Comment: @BobReynolds 1.8.0_66

Comment: @Fildor yes i mind the case. I don't know if Stream.of(stream) would work but the call to Stream.of is not working.

Comment: OK, let's consider the Stream.of Problem another question and concentrate on the List conversion error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems that you use java compiler language level lower than 8.
Try compiling from command line with

```
javac -source 8
```

Also check your language level project setting in IDE.

For example, output from IDEA 2016 hides info about used language level, but provide info about javac version

```
  Information:Using javac 1.8.0_101 to compile java sources
    Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'demo_04'
    Information:8/1/16 2:13 PM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 1s 403ms
    /tmp/1/src/JavaStreamExample.java
    Error:(16, 49) java: incompatible types: java.util.List<java.lang.Object> cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.String>
```

Comment: God i feel so dumb, yes this was a compiler version problems, i kept modifying the library without checking the compiler version.... Ty anyway.